# Spurious errors detected with deleted copy assignment?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following trivial struct

```
  struct crazy
    {
     const int i = 10;
     };
```

which is clearly not copyable. Indeed if I have two objects of that type, say
object1 and object2, and try a statement like

```
  object1 = object2;
```

both compilers I deal with, namely clang 3.4.2 and gcc 4.8.3 (well, they probably are outdated...), complain and reject the code with reasonable and
similar diagnostics.

But why, in that case, gcc detects an error also in the initialization of the
const member i ? Such error is detected no matter I change "const" with "constexpr".

Comment: They're not massively outdated; according to Wikipedia, [the current stable version of GCC is 4.9.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=GNU_Compiler_Collection&oldid=646104167) and [the current stable version of clang is 3.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Clang&oldid=645644021).

Comment: are you using the -std=c++11 flag in gcc?

Comment: @NathanOliver: of course; I did.

Comment: It *is* copyable, but not assignable. Which you demonstrated correctly.

Comment: Is the third error you're mentioning `error: non-static const member 'const int crazy::i', can't use default assignment operator`? It's just that it's a bit of extra output that comes with g++ which means the same thing as the prior two complaints.

Comment: @Quentin: Right, not assignable; this is enough to issue an error in the initialization? clang doesn't.

Comment: @Petesh: yes, it's that. So I must argue that it is not a NEW error?

Answer (score 5):

The errors I get are:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:10:13: error: use of deleted function ‘crazy& crazy::operator=(const crazy&)’
     object1 = object2;
             ^
test.cpp:3:8: note: ‘crazy& crazy::operator=(const crazy&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct crazy
        ^
test.cpp:3:8: error: non-static const member ‘const int crazy::i’, can’t use default assignment operator
```

The first error is because the assignment operator is deleted, as you say. The second is part of the note explaining why it was deleted: the error that would be generated by the default definition if it weren't deleted. Neither have anything to do with the initialisation of the const member.

If you're asking why the compiler thinks you might want both: because both are helpful to diagnose the problem. Maybe you shouldn't be copying the object, in which case the first tells that you can't. Maybe you want to, in which case the second tells you why you can't.

Comment: I believe it's the output error difference between `clang` and `g++` that the OP is asking about - clang only produces one error and one note, while g++ produces two errors and one note. The second error from g++ seems to be a detail that gets rolled into the note from clang (`note: copy assignment operator of 'crazy' is implicitly deleted because field 'i' is of const-qualified type 'const int'`)

Comment: @Petesh: Indeed, different authors made different decisions about the trade-off between detail and brevity in their error messages, so one is slightly longer and more informative than the other. But that's not a particularly interesting or answerable question; I was answering the question of why GCC gives the extra information, since that's what was asked.